# Xml data Node values need to save into Database table

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Computer Name="WH7" Processior="Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P9600 @ 2.66GHz" 
          Manufacturer="Dell Inc." Model="Latitude E6500" Domain="WORKGROUP" 
          RAM="3536 MB" ServiceTag="DGQKTJ1">
    <BIOS Manufacturer="Dell Inc." Version="Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A19"/>
</Computer>
```

I want to save root node (i.e `<Computer>`) attribute values and subnode values (i.e `BIOS`) into `Asset` table below.

```
Create Table Asset
(
   AssetId int Identity(100, 1),
   Name varchar(50),
   Processor varchar(50),
   Manufacturer varchar(100),
   Model varchar(100),
   Domain varchar(100),
   RAM  varchar(100),
   ServiceTag varchar(100),
   Version varchar(100)
)
```

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily extract the information from the `<Computer>` node and insert it into `Asset`:
(*PS: Note: it's a **processor** - not a "processior" (no `i` after the two `s`)* )

```
DECLARE @Input XML

SET @Input = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Computer Name="WH7" Processor="Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P9600 @ 2.66GHz" 
          Manufacturer="Dell Inc." Model="Latitude E6500" Domain="WORKGROUP" 
          RAM="3536 MB" ServiceTag="DGQKTJ1">
    <BIOS Manufacturer="Dell Inc." Version="Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A19"/>
</Computer>'

INSERT INTO dbo.Asset(Name, Processor, Manufacturer, Model, Domain, RAM, ServiceTag)
    SELECT
        Name = @Input.value('(/Computer/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Processor = @Input.value('(/Computer/@Processor)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Manufacturer = @Input.value('(/Computer/@Manufacturer)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Model = @Input.value('(/Computer/@Model)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Domain = @Input.value('(/Computer/@Domain)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        RAM = @Input.value('(/Computer/@RAM)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        ServiceTag = @Input.value('(/Computer/@ServiceTag)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

But what's totally unclear is how you want to insert the `<BIOS>` node into this table, and how you'll keep those two rows apart - or if they are linked somehow (so you'll know which BIOS belongs to which Computer.....)